# Postgres/PHP - What is the standard way to retrieve the ID of an inserted row?

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I have searched on Google and read a couple of articles on how different people approach this problem, but I was wondering what the ***standard*** way of solving it is and also, which one will work best for my situation.

I have an AJAX page that creates a new question and I need to know how to retrieve the ID from the insert query within the same php file, on the next line.

It looks something like this:

```
$r = pg_query("INSERT INTO questions (audit_id, type_id, order) VALUES (1,1,1)");
// Fetch ID from $r here...
```

I have seen the `mysql_insert_id()` function for MySQL and heard that `pg_last_oid()` is similar for PostgreSQL, but the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-oid.php) claims that it is deprecated and will be removed soon. I have also seen the use of `CURRVAL('my_sequence_table.id')` but I'm not sure if this will work with the AJAX since that might raise a race condition.

Can somebody please tell me the ***standard*** PHP/PostgreSQL way to solve this problem? I would greatly appreciate any comments.

P.S. I miss Ruby on Rails!

Comment: oh BTW, pg_last_oid is certainly not a good idea.  Tables no longer have OIDs by default.

Comment: @alvherre - Yeah, I caught that somewhere in my reading. What does the O in OID stand for anyway?

Comment: "object".  Note that OIDs are still used to identify system objects (i.e. tables, schemas, databases, etc).

Comment: @alvherre - Thanks. Interesting to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has the notion of autoincrement fields, PostgreSQL has the notion of *sequences*. A Postgres sequence is a named database object whose value can be increased. Please see this [FAQ](http://neilconway.org/docs/sequences/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. After some more reading, I think I will use the `RETURNING id` option.

Answer (score 5):

Probably your best bet is to use `INSERT INTO questions ... VALUES (1,1,1) RETURNING audit_id`, as that will give you the right value whether you plug the value manually or through a sequence.

Note that the `currval()` trick should certainly work if you get the same session -- `currval()` is guaranteed to return the same value that the sequence delivered to your session, regardless of what other concurrent sessions are doing.  It could only cause a problem if you have a connection pooler that somehow uses a different connection for the first query than the second query, but it would be quite broken a pooler if it did that.  I know of no pooler that does things that way.

**Update**: See the pg_get_serial_sequence() function, which takes a table and column name and returns the associated sequence name.  It is more practical to use than hardcoding the sequence name in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your input on `RETURNING` verses `currval()`. It's nice to see what track others take.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `CURRVAL('my_sequence_table.id')` option.

It shouldn't cause a race condition for you as it will return the latest value *for the current session* and these will be two consecutive statements in the same session.